# How do I protect a user/home directory from deletion?

Tags: permissions, user-management

A few hours ago, somebody logged into my VPS and deleted my home directory. Needless to say, there were very important files in my home directory, and I don't want to let it happen again.

I want to create a protected user that cannot be deleted, even by sudo. For example, the `rm` command would not work on its home directory, and the `deluser` or `userdel` commands cannot be used on it. *Not even with sudo.*

**EDIT**

So, unexpected *miracle* - my friend ended up creating a forced backup utility called `STEALTHY` which managed to snag my home directory, and I only lost a few hours of work.

Comment: `chattr +i file` for more info `man chattr`

Comment: chattr +i won't prevent root deleting the file.

Comment: You're missing the point of the privileged/root user. It's designed to be able to do **everything** on your system, including fully annihilating it. That's why you shouldn't give root permissions to just everyone. Only give users access to what they actually need to be able to do by setting specific sudo rules in your sudoers file.

Comment: That's a silly idea. Instead, make sure somebody can't just login into my VPS.

Comment: @Oldskool I'm not giving root permissions to just everyone, that's silly. There was a user named `stealthy`, but they're gone now.

Comment: @user68186 I'm beginning to doubt Ask Ubuntu. I already know common sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to protect a directory for being deleted by root. If someone has root-access to your server, everything is open and security of the server is breached.

Restore of a good current backup is the only thing that will help you.

Comment: Then why does root get some permission denied errors when indexing the root file system recursively?

Comment: Indexing only reads directories and files, I think. Maybe you get permission errors on some virtual files in /dev or /proc. But normal files can't be protected from root. You might have to remove -i (immutable) attribute, to delete a file, but root can do that easily.